# How to add/insert row in Kendo Grid?

Tags: jquery

Is this is anyway to add/insert row in Kendo Grid when the bounded dataSource changed(insert/remove/add)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Working Demo here click here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VMrqS/) http://jsfiddle.net/VMrqS/

**or** this http://jsfiddle.net/D3rSk/7/

I read this link for this demo to help you: hope this come handy to you: http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/ui-widgets/grid/walkthrough.aspx

This will show the add new row or delete example.

**code**

```
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                            },
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                        Freight: { type: "number" },
                                        ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                        OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                        ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 10,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        height: 250,
                        filterable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        columns: [{
                                field:"OrderID",
                                filterable: false
                            },
                            "Freight", {
                                field: "OrderDate",
                                format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                            },
                            "ShipName",
                            "ShipCity",
                            { command: "destroy", title: " ", width: "110px"}
                           ]

                    });
                });
​
```